# How to calculate $\int_{|x| < r} |x|^n dm$? Integral over ball.

Tags: measure-theory

How to calculate $\int_{|x| < r} |x|^n dm$? For some $r$, say $r=3$.

There are some simpler integrals here:

[Indefinite Integral of Absolute Value of x? Is there a closed form solution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1467805/248602)

But this one confuses me a bit, since it has the ball and $n$ which may be even or odd.

And here's a particular answer with this in $\mathbb{R}^n$ case, but it lacks details:

[Computing the Lebesgue integral over a ball](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3021360/computing-the-lebesgue-integral-over-a-ball)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\int_{|x|<r}|x|^{n}dx=\int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{0}^{r}|\rho\theta|^{n}\rho^{n-1}d\rho d\theta=\omega_{n-1}\int_{0}^{r}\rho^{n}\rho^{n-1}d\rho=\omega_{n-1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{2n}\cdot r^{2n},
\end{align*}
where $\omega_{n-1}$ is the surface area of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: Can you explain more, what happens here?

Comment: The spherical integration method is such that letting $x=\rho\theta$, where $\rho$ runs in the radius of the ball, and $\theta$ runs in $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: Where does $p^{n-1}$ come from?

Comment: That is the some sort of the result of Jacobian.

Comment: I cannot find a reference that gives the formulation that you give.

Comment: Look at Folland Real Analysis Second Edition page 78.